# User defined palette in combination with cbrange

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have the following figure in gnuplot 4.6.2

[image: Sample graph]

With the minimum productive example

```
set xrange [-2:10];
set yrange [-2:10];

set size ratio -1
set pm3d map

set palette defined (-20 "#0060ad", 0 "#ffffff", 100 "#dd181f" )
set cbrange [-20:100]

splot x*y
```

However, this is not completely what I want. I actually want the value for -20, to have the same intensity as +20.

I tried two things, as you can see below.

If I change `-20` in the `palette` and the `cbrange` to `-100`, I get the figure at the left. This is basically the graph that I want. However, if I set `cbrange` to `[-20:100]`, while keeping the palette at `-100`, I get the figure at the right. This is not what I want, I want the colorbox to start at `-20`. How can I achieve that?

[image: Example tries]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. You say, the intensity at -20 and +20 should be the same. What about the values for +20 to +100? With `set palette defined (-20 "#0060ad", 0 "#ffffff", 20 "#dd181f", 100 "#dd181f" )` you have similar intensities at -20 and +20, but +20 and +100 are also equal.

Comment: @Christoph, with same intensity I mean, -20 light blue, +20  light red. Basically, the map should look like the left one in the second figure I show. The colorbox, however, starts now at -100 (because I have that in the palette). What I want, is the colorbox running `[-20:100]`. However, if I do that, I get the right figure.

Comment: Ok, I get it. At the moment I don't see any other option than just manually interpolating the dark blue to get the actual value for -20 which you must then set explicitely. The whole number range you give in `palette defined` is always mapped to the whole cbrange. You could play around with `set palette functions`, but in your case it is easier to just interpolate the light blue: `set cbrange [-20:100]; set palette defined (-20 "#ccdfef", 0 "white", 100 "#dd181f")`.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks. That is actually what I also tried, the interpolation. How did you come up with `#ccdfef`? If you post that as an answer, it'll work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understood, you want to define the colors at -100, 0 and +100, but use only the part between -20 and +100.

At the moment I don't see any other option than just manually doing a linear interpolation between the dark blue at -100 and white at 0 to get light blue, which in your case is `#ccdfef`:

```
red = int(255*0.8) = 0xcc
green = int(0x60 + (0xff-0x60)*0.8) = 0xdf
blue = int(0xad + (0xff - 0xad)*0.8) = 0xee
```

The problem is, that the numerical values given to `set palette defined` aren't absolute values, but rather relative values which are always mapped the the whole cbrange.

```
set xrange [-2:10]
set yrange [-2:10]

set size ratio -1
set pm3d map

set palette defined (-20 "#ccdfef", 0 "#ffffff", 100 "#dd181f" )
set cbrange [-20:100]
set isosamples 100
splot x*y notitle
```

[image]